# Delete azure resource group after 30 days of creation based on tags using azure policy

Tags: azure, azure-policy, jsontemplate

How can I delete azure resource groups (having tag:delete-after-30-days) after 30 days of creation based on tags using azure policy.
So far I came up with this -

```
    {
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
                },
                {
                    "not": {
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                        "exists": "false"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                    "equals": "delete-after-30-days"
                },
                {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/createdTime",
                    "greaterThan": "[utcNow('-P30D')]"
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "displayName": "Tag Name",
                "description": "Name of the tag to identify resource groups for deletion"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But Azure giving me an error -

- Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'greater-than' on object of type 'LeafExpressionDefinition'. Path 'greaterThan'.'.

Comment: Instead of using Azure Policy, Why not to use an Automation account scheduled on daily basis and a Powershell script to do this task?

Comment: Are you using terraform or ARM template? @Indrajeet Singh

Comment: @Jahnavi , I am using policy definition here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To delete azure resource groups having `tag: delete-after-30-days` after 30 days of creation based on tags using azure policy:

According to this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-functions), Instead of using the `utcnow( )` policy function, Use
`addDays(dateTime, DaysToAdd)` function which will meet your requirements. It was used as follows:

```bash
[addDays(utcNow(), -30)]
```

*The above function helps in policy implementation by calculating from the current date time to the 30 days after creation*.

***I've created the below policy definition from Azure Portal and it was successfully created.***

I modified your code as below and added the below policy rule under policy rule code area while creating the policy definition.

```bash
{
"mode": "Indexed",
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
   "allOf": [
    {
     "field": "type",
     "equals":"Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
    },
    {
    "not": {
      "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'),  ']')]",
      "exists": "false"
     }
  },
    {
    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
    "equals": "delete-after-30-days"
   },
   {
    "field": "tags['delete-after-30-days']",
    "greater": "[addDays(utcNow(), -30)]"
   }
 ]
},
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
     }
  },
"parameters": {
   "tagName": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Tag Name",
      "description": "Name of the tag to identify resource groups for deletion"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

***Policy definition got created as shown:***

[image]

[image]